# Zend Framework 1 and Doctrine 1:- Configuring Memcache

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, memcached

Does Configuring memcache in Zend Application requires **php_memcache.dll** to be installed first or **memcached.exe** to be installed.Not able to connect memcache to port 11211.
Any help would be appreciated.
I need to configure memcache with Zend to cache the Doctrine queries.
My bootstrap.php file:-

```
public function _initDoctrineCache()
{

$this->bootstrap('doctrine');
$manager=Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
$cacheDriver=null;
if(extension_loaded('memcache')){

    $servers=array(
      'host'=>'127.0.0.1',
      'port'=> 11211
      'persistent'=>true
        );
}

$cacheDriver=new Doctrine_Cache_Memcache(
     array(
       'servers'=>$servers,
       'compression'=>false
        )
    );

    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'Memcached', $frontend, $backend);
}
```

Please help!!I have been fa